# ASP.NET MVC DropDownList Validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, drop-down-menu

I have

```
[DisplayName("Country")]
public List<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }
```

property in strong-type Model View class for DropDownList.

When I try to check if the ModelState.IsValid on form postback it's always false & error for *Countries* tells "Can't convert [value] to SelectListItem" or some of a kind.

I figured out there is no straight-forward mapping for drop down selected value (looks like I'll have to read value from Form value collection), but how can I ignore binding and validation for List property? I just want to make ModelState.IsValid attribute to be true if all the other fields are populated properly.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is it because the value submitted is of type `String` or `Country` rather than a list of `SelectListItem` or `List<SelectListItem>`.

What are you binding to the control in the UI?

try

```
[DisplayName("Country")]
public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }
```

Where `Country` is the type name from your DAL.

EDIT:
Based on the error you are recieving, it sounds like the model is expecting the value to be a `String` so try swapping `List<Country>` for `List<String>`.

```
[DisplayName("Country")]
public List<string> Countries { get; set; }
```

Comment: still the same ModelState error. Can't convert from string to Country

Comment: So it needs to be a String then. The error message is telling you what you need to do.

Comment: But it can't be a string, because it's a list of something :)
I abandoned my attempts to use DropDownListFor and use DropDownList with [name] attribute that points to a string property in view model

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used workaround.

My model now:

```
class Model
{
...
  [DisplayName("Country")]
  List<Country> Countries;

  Guid CountrySelected    <-- new field! 
...
}
```

I use Html.DropDownList("CountrySelected", Model.Countries.Select(x => new SelectItemList.. )

instead  of HtmlDropDownListFor. HtmlDropDownListFor maps [id selected] to List not to CountrySelected property. Now [id selected] is mapped to CountrySelected